# Вызов лямбда-функции, которая содержит лямбда-функцию

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь понять как в этом коде вызывается лямбда-функция

```
auto vglambda = [](auto printer) {
   return [=](auto&& ... ts) {   
       printer(std::forward<decltype(ts)>(ts)...);
   };
};
auto p = vglambda( [](auto v1, auto v2, auto v3)    
                       { std::cout << v1 << v2 << v3; } );
p(1, 'a', 3.14);  // OK: выводит 1a3.14
```

Как я думал , v1,v2,v3 должны передаваться в место ,где находится auto printer,но они ,как я понимаю, передаются в (auto&& ... ts),почему так происходит и что тогда передается в auto printer? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vglambda` - это лямбда, которая принимает лямбду и возвращает еще одну лямбду
`[=](auto&& ... ts)` в которой вызывается передаваемая лямбда.

То есть `auto printer` это лямбда, которую вы передаете:

```
[](auto v1, auto v2, auto v3) { std::cout << v1 << v2 << v3; }
```

И `vglambda` возвращает лямбду, которая вызовет передаваемую лямбду.

Когда вы пишите:

```
p(1, 'a', 3.14);
```

Вы вызываете лямбду `(auto&& ... ts)`, которую возвращает лямбда `vglambda`, и которая в себе вызовет лямбду, которую вы передали на:

```
auto p = vglambda( [](auto v1, auto v2, auto v3)    
                   { std::cout << v1 << v2 << v3; } );
```

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь!